# Showing this subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I got this apparently easy fact in an example in a real analysis textbook, assumed without proof in the solution of some other problem not worth mentioning, but after some effort I think I'm not able to fix the correct ideas to prove it.

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational or zero and $f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \frac{1}{q}$ if $\frac{p}{q}$ is a irreductible fraction, with $p\ne 0$ (where of course $p$ and $q$ are integers and $q\ne 0$). Then, for $\varepsilon > 0$, the set $F_{\varepsilon} := \left\{ x\in [a,b]: f(x)\ge\varepsilon\right\} $ is finite.

The text says that it is so because $F_a$ is the set of the irreductible fractions of $[a,b]$ whose denominators are $\le\frac{1}{a}$, but after some effort I was not able to show that this set is indeed finite. I assumed it is not, but I don't know how to use the fact that the fractions are irreductible to show the finitude of $F_a$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You used $a$ twice. Is that intended?

Comment: You probably also assume that $q>0$, otherwise the representation $p/q$ is not unique.

Comment: Hint : First show that $q$ is limited by the condition $f(x)\ge a$. Then, look at the possible values $p$

Comment: @KennyLau I just need to prove when $a$ is some fixed real positive number, although it may sounded that the fact is stated for any $a>0$.

Comment: @AnalyticHarmony You probably mean, for $\varepsilon > 0$, the set $F_\varepsilon := \{ x \in [\color{red}a,b] \mid f(x) \ge \color{red}\varepsilon \}$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1: for every $n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$, the level set $L_n = \{ x \in [a,b] \mid f(x) = \frac1n \}$ is finite.

Lemma 2: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, the set $\{ n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\} \mid \frac 1 n \ge \varepsilon \}$ is finite.

Then you are done, since the set required is just the indexed product of the first sets (each of which is finite) indexed by the second set (which is finite).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try a few and see what happens. $F_1$ is the set of integers in $[a,b]$ (rational numbers with denominator less than or equal to $1$), which is very much finite. What are $F_{1/2}$ and $F_{1/3}$? Now do you have an idea why they are all finite?